# Android Studio - Error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android-studio-2.2

[Screen Shot #1 - Android Studio Project Gradle Build View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puIl8.jpg)

[Screen Shot #2 - Android Studio Project Gradle Sync View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0yNQ.jpg)

Going through the "Android Studio 2.2 Development Essentials book" and following along with the tutorial in chapter 3. Everything was OK until I completed a task in the Development Essentials book (chapter 3, page 24 in book) that said,

> As we can see from the component tree hierarchy, the user interface
>   layout consists of a layout parent with a single child in the form of
>   a TextView object. If Android Studio has used a RelativeLayout manager
>   for the project, the first step is to convert it to a
>   ConstraintLayout. ConstraintLayout is a new and flexible layout
>   manager that is used in most projects in this book. To achieve this
>   conversion, right-click on the content_android_sample entry in the
>   Component Tree and select the Convert RelativeLayout to
>   ConstraintLayout menu option as shown below:

Upon completion of the above quoted tutorial task (in chapt. 3 of the Development Essentials book), an error was presented that said:

***Error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1***

Also, a rendering error was listed as well that said:

***Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (    Add constraint-layout library dependency to the project, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)***

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Please see screen shots attached (above). I'm new to Android Studio.

Thank you very much for your time.

I am using the following OS and Android Studio version below:

Win7 professional 64 bit OS

Android Studio 2.2

Build# AI-145,3330264, Built on October 6, 2016

Answer (score 22):

You need add check in..

exist a icon with name "SDK Manager" just click

open `Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools`

And in this dialog add:

- ConstraintLayout for Android
- Solver for ConstrainLayout

[image]

Then, here only you need close and open Android Studio.

Maybe only you can update to:

`compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'`

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Had to delay my project and hope to restart it soon.

Answer (score 4):

Or update your dependency to:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:latest_version'
```

Comment: That depends on the versions installed on the local machine.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I had to delay my project. Will notify you when I start the project again.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your error. Go to your `build.gradle` and change your `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta7'`  to `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta7' or to any latest`

Comment: Thank you. Had to delay my project. Will pick up this thread again when I restart the project. Thanks again for you help.